# How to trigger a python script on the django server for the particular form input?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

i want to make a search box on my website. I want the output of the particular searchbox input  to be generated by particular file which is mapped on the server for the given output.

for ex:- fib 10

will run fib.py and give the response will be the result of the fib.py

Answer (score 1):

You could use `subprocess` module to run command and take the output.

**Update 1**

Example view:

```
import subprocess

def runCmd(request):

    cmd = request.POST.get('cmd')
    param = request.POST.get('param')

    codeDir = '/path/to/py/file/'
    absoluteCodePath = codeDir + cmd + '.py'

    result = subprocess.check_output([absoluteCodePath, param])

    return result
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html as an example subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"]) returns 'Hello World!\n'

Comment: This is, of course, if you can't just import the python module and use it natively.

Comment: The question does not say how to import a python module or script natively. It asks how to run externally since the name of the script is a parameter too.

Comment: I think if you read the question carefully he is not fully excluding the possibility. Your answer will work though.

Comment: If I were him, I would use python natively. But there are cases where you need to run commands on the system to collect data, integrate with the system or simply to call external tools which are developed by third parties. Which is the case I have faced with my customers.

Comment: well this makes sense though, if you want to say execute a batch job, something that takes long, then this works. Up vote from me.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? Just import your file/module and use it, this is the correct way.

Lets say you have this code in `fib.py`:

```
def calculate(.....):
    #code. ...
    return result
```

Now in you other file, lets say it's `views.py` just do:

```
import fib

# this is the search view
def search(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
       # other code
       fib.calculate(param) # where param is the value of the search field
```

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.. but no there's no reason to use `subprocess` and execute a file and get the value returned...